# Symfony sandbox 1.4 sandbox on IIS7 all I get is response code 500

Tags: php, iis-7, symfony-1.4, error-reporting

I am asked to maintain a website but the develop environment hasn't been set up properly. First it was redirecting all requests to the production server but after fixing that all I get is response 500.

The application is set up in IIS to show detailed error messages remote and local(under error pages).

The index.php has the following content:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
?>
```

/apps/frontend/config/settings.yml for dev:

```
dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
```

I would expect some sort of error reporting here instead of a 500 response. Is there something I have forgotten to do?

Comment: What does the server log says ?

Comment: @j0k The PHP error log says the SQL server doesn't exist or the user credentials are wrong. I would expect this to show in the browser as I've set every setting I can think of to do so.

Comment: Why is your debug flag on `false` here `$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', false);`?

Comment: @VladJula-Nedelcu You are correct, setting it to true will dump the error in the browser. If you want the reputation I'll select it as the answer if you add it as such. I haven't worked with 1.4 that much and have yet to go through the documentation. Found the error in the PHP log and informed the admin that sql server isn't working so the problem is fixed for now. Not sure I'd like to see the messages from external sites so set it to false for now until I work on it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your debug flag to `true` here:

`$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', false);`